# datetimepicker (Custom)

Tags: c#, winforms, datetimepicker

So I am using this code:

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "HH:mm tt";
```

But it refuses to give me the correct minutes.  Instead it gives me 0 but I want the real time like 04:48.

Comment: please be more specific is this webforms, winforms, WPF?

Comment: I got it in a button, do i really need to be more specific its not like you need everything, thats the only code in the winform so yeah

Comment: It's necessary to know if it was winforms or not.

Comment: How are you using `dateTimePicker1`?  Can you show code as to how you are trying to render the Date/Time?

Comment: if i use the same formatter i see the current time. Maybe you took a look at exactly 0 minutes :) (just kidding) but i don't see the AM/PM switch but that can by my computer settings.

Comment: Why do you use the am/pm specifier (tt) when also using 24 hour time?

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "hh:mm tt";
```

Answer (score 1):

It Depends on how you set the dateTimePicker, if the dateTimePicker has no value ofcourse your control will display 0 minutes.

To use the DateTimePicker for times, set the Format property to either Time or Custom. Then
specify the format:

```
dateTimePicker1.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Custom;
dateTimePicker1.CustomFormat = "HH:mm tt";
```

That should work.

Comment: I think that's what his original question shows that he's doing, except you're specifying 12-hour format for the hours instead of 24.